# Сколько максимально можно сохранить в Bundle при сворачивании?

Tags: java, android

Сохраняю данные в кэше

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putSerializable(SHEDULE, shedule);
    outState.putSerializable(RING, ringShedule);
    //outState.putString(DOC, doc_);
}
```

`doc_` хранит в себе достаточно длинную строку, в которой содержится html страница. Если ее не сохранять, то весь кэш загрузится и активити восстановится. Если же сохранять, то активити не восстановится, а загрузится главная активити. Я так понимаю приложение сохраняет, но эту длинную строку восстановить не может?

Comment: А в логах что-нибудь есть? Есть подозрение, что строка настолько большая, что вылетает OutOfMemory, что запускает процесс очистки памяти, а под раздачу попадает и ваша вторая Activity

Comment: лучше эту длинную строку складывать в файл и выгружать ее по необходимости. так будет безопаснее для данных

Comment: @miha_dev в логах вообще ничего не отображается, только весь процесс запуска главного активити. Пробовал в логи отобразить процесс восстановления строки, но даже он не отображается. Я использу largeHeap и доступно 268mb

Comment: Это не кеш. Это `Bundle`

Comment: @miha_dev сделал по-вашему совету, хотя макисмальный размер для хранения все равно интересен

Comment: Судя по англоязычному SO - максимальный размер 1MB

Answer (score 2):

Из-за того что данные Bundle'а летают по IPC, лимит на них 1MB.
Если верить англоязычному [ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9952313/1482723)

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы.