# Обмен информации между Activity

Tags: android

**UPD**
В общем по советам - попробовал сделать через `ViewPager` и `Fragments` - всё вышло, но вот вопрос по сбору информации остался.

Как взять информацию из `View`, который не отображен на экране? Т.к. если я правильно понял, `View` (как и активити, табы и т.д.)? которого в данный момент времени на экране нету - не существует (null).

Всего - 4 фрагмента, в каждом есть `Checkbox`, `EditText` и т.д.

Кнопка отправки - в `MainActivity`. Только как от неё обращаться к фрагментам, которые не отображены на экране - не могу понять.

Mainactivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    static final String TAG = "myLogs";
    static final int PAGE_COUNT = 4;

    ViewPager pager;
    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        btn.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    private class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return PageFragment.newInstance(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return PAGE_COUNT;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            String title = null;
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    title = "Users";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    title =  "System";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    title =  "IO";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    title = "Other Text";
                    break;
            }
        return title;
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        EditText et = (EditText) pager.findViewById(R.id.user_phone_1_et);
        EditText et2 = (EditText) pager.findViewById(R.id.z1_alarm_et);
        et2.setText(et.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

Pagefragment.java

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {

    static final String ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER = "arg_page_number";

    int pageNumber;
    int backColor;

    static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
        PageFragment pageFragment = new PageFragment();
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER, page);
        pageFragment.setArguments(arguments);
        return pageFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        pageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        View view = null;
        switch (pageNumber) {
            case 0:
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.users, null);
                break;
            case 1:
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.system, null);
                break;
            case 2:
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.input_output, null);
                break;
            case 3:
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.other_text, null);
                break;
        }


        return view;
    }

}
```

[image: Первый фрагмент]

[image: 4 фрагмент]

Comment: я не понимаю что нужно сделать и какая проблема? 
Как можно получить данные если их нет и активити (вкладка) ещё даже не создана. опишите проблему ясней пожалуйста.

Comment: Единственно правильное решение - это перестать использовать устаревшие еще во времена викингов технологии, и начать использовать ViewPager и фрагменты.

Comment: исправил, и еще вопрос в ViewPager я так понимаю для разных страниц - используется одно activity?

Comment: Посмотрите туториал по `ViewPager`, и все станет ясно.

Comment: @YuraGeyts, http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/228-urok-125-viewpager.html

Comment: Не нужно писать в заголовке вопроса об обновлении, вопрос и так будет поднят на главную. В теле вопроса помечайте, что добавили.

Comment: @pavlofff понял. Вопрос полностью обновлен.

Answer (score 1):

Информацию, которая в данный момент не отображается на экране, но потребуется в будущем, нужно сохранять в сущности, не зависящие от жизненного цикла активити\фрагментов - в Bundle, БД, SharedPreferences, xml-файл или коллекцию объектов-моделей. Конкретный способ выбирается исходя из решаемых задач. Затем нужная информация извлекается из хранилища, а не из View.

В Bundle данные помещаются при кратковременных сохранениях состояния в расчете на то, что к ним требуется вернуться в текущем расположении - повороты устройства, перемещения вперед-назад по стеку. Данный способ имеет ограничения по объему сохраняемой информации (считается, что он [ограничен 1Мб](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/486966/177345)) и по времени хранения (как максимум - текущая сессия). Это своего рода промежуточный буфер и , как правило, не предназначен для перемещения информации между объектами.

Во внешнее хранилище (БД, файл, SharedPreferences) данные помещаются для долгосрочного хранения, когда требуется восстановить их и после закрытия приложения.
По удобству доступа SharedPreferences значительно проще, но они имеют ограничения на типы сохраняемых данных и, в основном, не предназначены для промежуточного хранения состояний, а больше для нечасто изменяемых установок, вроде настроек приложения.
При большом количестве данных предпочтение за БД.

Для хранения промежуточных состояний в пределах одного объекта (такого, как активити) удобно использовать объект-модель, которая хранит текущее состояние ее дочерних элементов (данных. введенных в фрагментах). Объект создается при создании активити и затем фрагменты записывают в него свою информацию по мере ее поступления, а так же забирают ее при пересоздании фрагмента, чтобы восстановить то, что уже было введено ранее. Данный способ действует в пределах одного запуска активити. При выходе из активити данные будут утрачены, поэтому, если они потребуются при возврате на активити, нужно их сохранить в более надежном хранилище перед выходом (файл, БД). Так же необходимо предусмотреть обработку поворотов устройства и сохранение самого объекта-модели в таком случае - это либо сериализация и помещение в Bundle, либо [такой способ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/428687/177345).

Comment: Подскажите, а если в БД в 1 таблице - 40 ячеек для записи, можно ли допустим записать 7 значений из 1 фрагмента, потом во втором фрагменте, добавить еще 8, и т.д.?

Comment: @YuraGeyts Ваша БД - как вы считаете удобным, так и пишите. Хотя по работе с СУБД книги по 1000 страниц пишут, как туда значения записывать и организовывать все это дело. Обычно таблицы организуют по какому то структурному признаку, а не валят все в кучу в одной. В вашем случае вообще я бы остановился на сохранении в SharedPreferences

Answer (score 0):

к TabHost привязываем LocalActivityManager, пример:

```
LocalActivityManager localActMgr = new LocalActivityManager(this, false);
localActMgr.dispatchCreate(savedInstanceState);
TabHost tabs = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
tabs.setup(localActMgr);
```

Далее в любом activity наследнике вы можете обращатся к остальным, пример есть activity_one и activity_two нужно получить данные activity_one в activity_two:
объект родительского Activity LocalActivityManager должен быть public

```
ParentActivity parentActivity = (ParentActivity) this.getParent();
parentActivity.localActMgr.getActivity(//Здесь String id - вашего наследника//);
```